# Event receiver takes a break

Tags: sharepoint, eventreceiver

I have an event receiver that listens on three list. When I save Data, about 7 elements are changed, so the event receiver has to start 7 times.

Inside the ULS-log I can see the event receiver does what he should, but between each of them there is a break of exactly 3 minutes. I would have expeceted that the event receivers starts immediatly.

Is this a normal behaviour? And can this be tweaked?

Answer (score 0):

With SharePoint you can have both synchronous and asynchronous event receivers. Make sure your receiver is of the synchronous kind if you want it to run immidiately (the method name should end in -ing as opposed to -ted).

Comment: It is asynchronous and should be. I just expected this to happen in a time range of a few seconds, not minutes

Comment: Usually it's almost instantanous -- IIRC, it's the timer service that executes async handlers, so maybe restarting it helps (or maybe it was stopped when the event was triggered). Do note, though, that async event receivers in SharePoint are buggy. They don't necessarily trigger in the same order as the events occur and sometimes they trigger more than once for the same event or not at all.